# Get Exact Match Rows in same Sequence using SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I have two table and data are in following format. I need help to get only match rows using SQL Server Query from table number 2 in same sequence as appearing in table number 1.

**tab 1:**

sno    codeseq         lno    docno 
3845   255636363      1    anydoc 
3846   255696969      1    anydoc 
3847   255747474      1    anydoc 
3865   255646464      2    anydoc 
3866   255707070      2    anydoc

**tab 2**

sno    codeseq         lno    docno 
53951   255636363      21    demo1 
53952   255696969      21    demo1 
53953   255747474      21    demo1 
53954   255747474      21    demo1 
53955   255737373      21    demo1 
54086   255646464      22    demo1 
54087   255707070      22    demo1 
54088   255747474      22    demo1 
54089   255636363      115   demo2 
54090   255696969      115   demo2 
54091   255747474      115   demo2 
54092   255747474      116   demo2 
54093   255737373      116   demo2 
54094   255747474      116   demo2

I need output result in this format.

sno    codeseq         lno    docno 
53951   255636363      21    demo1 
53952   255696969      21    demo1 
53953   255747474      21    demo1 
54086   255646464      22    demo1 
54087   255707070      22    demo1 
54089   255636363      115   demo2 
54090   255696969      115   demo2 
54091   255747474      115   demo2

Comment: Ok we understand you have requirement but SO doesn't help you to code the requirement. Put some effort and you will see its not that difficult.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OP asking to solve problem.

Comment: @almasshaikh: This is my first question on stackoverflow. I am unable to get result. Can you please read the comments given against kumar reply for this and suggest any suitable answer for this. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try this query.

```
SELECT T2.sno, T2.codeseq, T2.lno, T2.docno 
FROm Tab1 AS T1 
INNER JOIN Tab2 AS T2
ON T1.codeseq = T2.codeseq ORDER BY T2.lno ASC
```

Comment: Kumar: This do not fulfil my purpose. I only want to get match rows whereas this join return more rows whereas i need only match rows in exact sequence as i mentioned in result section of my question.

Comment: @narra : The above query select the rows from tab2 for the matched codeseq          in Tab1. What you are trying to tell from 'exact sequence'?

Comment: exact sequence mean. I have 5 rows in tbl 1. Three rows are belong to line number 1 and 2 rows are belongs to line number 2. I want to search these records in tbl 2 in exact sequence with line wise. As i mentioned in result file. First three rows of tbl 1 on line number 1 are matched with first 3 rows of tbl 2 at line number 22 docno demo1 (In same row seq as exists tbl 1) and then same rows find at line number 115 docno demo2 (row sequence tbl1). Second line number of table 1 has two records and these are matching with only two records of table 2 at line number 22 docno demo1.

Comment: So in overall result . I should have only eight rows as i mentioned in output result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sno
    ,codeseq
    ,lno
    ,docno
FROM tab2
WHERE sno + codeseq + lno + docno IN (
        SELECT sno + codeseq + lno + docno
        FROM tab1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if you are checking only code sequence):

```
select * from tab2 where codeseq in(select codeseq from tab1)
```